# How does php execute a function assigned to variable?

Tags: php

Ok, I didn't really know how to even phrase the question, but let me explain.

Suppose I have a variable:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__);
```

What happens if I assign `$file` to another variable?

```
$anotherVariable = $file;
```

Does the `dirname` function get executed each time I assign?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. PHP is imperative, so the right hand side of assignment expressions is *evaluated*, and the result stored "in the" left hand side (in the simple and almost ubiquitous case, the variable named on the left hand side).

```
$a = $b;  // Find the value of $b, and copy it into the value of $a
$a = 5 + 2; // Evaulate 5 + 2 to get 7, and store this in $a
$a = funcName(); // Evaluate funcName, which is equivalent to executing the code and obtaining the return value. Copy this value into $a
```

This gets a little more complex when you assign by reference ($a = &$b), but we needn't worry about that for now.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have closures like that.

> dirname(**FILE**)

this function returns a string.

> $anotherVariable = $file;

gives $anotherVariable that same string value.

so I believe the answer to your question is "no", it does not get executed each time.

Comment: Closure may be the wrong term, but php functions are not first class citizens

Answer (score 2):

## Answer to main question:

```
$a = function(){ echo "Hello!"; };
$a();
```

**Answers to minor questions:**

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__); 
//means: 
//"Evaluate/Execute function dirname() and store its return value in variable $file"
```

> What happens if I assign $file to another variable?

If we are talking about regular assignment ( `$anotherVariable = $file;` ),
 it just **copies the value** from `$file` to `$anotherVariable` both are independent variables.

> Does the dirname function get executed each time I assign?

No it does not. Because execution is done only with `()`. No `()` = No execution.

Answer (score 1):

No in any case.

PHP's functions are not identifiers which point to instance of class Function as you can see in Java, ActionScript, JavaScript etc... That's why you can't store a link to function itself to a variable. That's why any time you call the function it is in common the same as you include() a script to execute. Sure there are differences, but in context of this question including with include() and calling a function are almost identical.

Don't be confused with this case

```
function myFunc() {return 'hello world';}
$func = 'myFunc';
$a = $func();
echo $a; // hello world
```

Read about this case [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) This behavior is special for PHP. Not sure about other languages - maybe somwhere there's smth. similar to this, but I've never met it.